# JQuery AJAX - Assigning Callback Handlers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 3 functions.  One for each of the following scenarios:

- Begin
- Success
- Failure

I am not quite sure of 2 things:

1. The correct property names for these 3. I am using `beforeSend:`, `success:` and `failure:`
2. The correct way to call the handlers for these 3.

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $('.icon.delete.cosponsor').click(function () {

            var divId = $(this).attr("data-attr-divid");
            var recordId = $(this).attr("data-attr-id");
            $("#" + divId).fadeOut(300, function () { $("#" + divId).remove(); });

            //Delete a record
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Path/To/Action',
                    data: queryStr,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: OnBegin(),
                    success: OnSuccess(data),
                    failure: OnFailure(data),
                    timeout: 5000
                });


        });



/***********************************************
  AJAX Callback Handlers
 ***********************************************/
    function OnBegin() {

        $('#loading-area').show();
    }


    function OnSuccess(data) {

        $('#loading-area').hide();

        $.notification({
            content: 'Information saved successfully.' + data,
            error: false,
            timeout: 10000
        });
    }

    function OnFailure(request, error) {

        $('#loading-area').hide();
        $('#ValidationResultsArea').show();
        $.notification({
            content: 'Error saving data.',
            error: true,
            timeout: 10000
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: beforeSend, success, error. They're called automatically. Only success OR error will be called during an ajax request, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a reference to a function, not calling the function, look:

```
    $('.icon.delete.cosponsor').click(function () {

        var divId = $(this).attr("data-attr-divid");
        var recordId = $(this).attr("data-attr-id");
        $("#" + divId).fadeOut(300, function () { $("#" + divId).remove(); });

        //Delete a record
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Path/To/Action',
                data: queryStr,
                dataType: 'json', // <<<<< dataType != datatype
                beforeSend: OnBegin, // <<<<<
                success: OnSuccess, // <<<<<
                failure: OnFailure, // <<<<<
                timeout: 5000
            });


    });
```

Comment: Additionally, `failure` is not the same as `error`, and the property names are case sensitive, `datatype` is not the same as `dataType`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not failure it's "error" http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer. I believe that the use of success and failure is less common and many are using the following callbacks.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
          url: "callbacktestbackend.php",
    dataType : 'json'    })
                           .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                                                   console.log(data,
                                                                               textStatus,
                                                                               jqXHR.responseText);
                                                                                                                              })
                           .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                                                         console.log             
                                                                        (jqXHR.responseText,
                                                                         textStatus,
                                                                         errorThrown);
                                                                                                                              })
                           .always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                                                      console.log(data,
                                                                                  textStatus,
                                                                                  jqXHR);
                                                                                                                              });
```

You can mix and match the ones you want to use and add code to the function as you see fit.

---

From the jQuery ajax page:
Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.